# how to ajax Get result in a php file from another php file echo

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using a long polling script, where I want show result into user.php page "#updatapost" div which get result from update.php page echo'' with Ajax,

Please see my code for clear about my problem

Here, If I used any text as below for test purpose, Its work well

```
success: function(data){ 
        $("#updatetime").append("Test working");
```

But **I want to append here my update.php page echo' ';**

my script used at user.php page

```
function waitForMsg(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "update.php",
        async: true, 
        cache: false,
        timeout:50000, 

        success: function(data){
/* Here above I want to append update.php page echo */
            $("#updatepost").append(data.responseText); 
            setTimeout(
                waitForMsg, 
                1000 
            );
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
            addmsg("error", textStatus + " (" + errorThrown + ")");
            setTimeout(
                waitForMsg, 
                15000); 
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    waitForMsg(); 
});
```

My user.php page where result want to show

```
<div id="updatepost"> result will goes here from update.php page echo''; </div>
```

My update.php page

```
$u = mysqli_query($dbh,"SELECT * FROM updateside WHERE `parent_id`='".$parent."' AND `created` > '".$timestamp."' ORDER BY created DESC") or die(mysqli_error($dbh));
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($u)) {
$from_id = $row['from_id'];
$parent_id = $row['parent_id'];
$to_id = $row['to_id'];
$sub = $row['sub'];
$detail = $row['detail'];

echo '<div class="upbox" id="'.$parent_id.'">
// All result of above query
</div>';
}
```

Comment: Have a look at the Data parameter of the success function. This contains the answer from server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to append data from server you must return current result. In your example you return text but in js you try apped this text- that is your problem. This is a example:
user.php

```
$u = mysqli_query($dbh,"SELECT * FROM updateside WHERE `parent_id`='".$parent."' AND `created` > '".$timestamp."' ORDER BY created DESC") or die(mysqli_error($dbh));
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($u)) {
$result['from_id'] = $row['from_id'];
$result['parent_id'] = $row['parent_id'];
......
....

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($result);
exit;
}
```

and your success method

```
success: function(data){
if(data) {
//create your html structs as you access data : data.from_id or data.parent_id 
}

        },
```

Comment: please help me to access data that I am not clear. Is it like $("#updatetime").append().html('<div class="upbox1" id="'.$parent_id.'"> data.sub, data.detail, data.from_id, data.parent_id</div>')

Comment: If i use $("#updatetime").append().html('<div class="upbox1" id=' + parent_id + '> '+ data.sub +'</div>'); Its show function sub() { [native code] }

Comment: Sir please help me to solved it. cannot access data with JS html

Comment: Are u here please. .